# How can I configure Android so that Chrome doesn't stop uploading when Chrome doesn't have the focus?

Tags: chrome-for-android, android-13, focus, uploads, samsung-galaxy-s-23

I have a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra running Android 13. I am uploading a large video to YouTube via https://www.youtube.com/upload and not the Android YouTube application. I notice that when Chrome doesn't have the focus for a few minutes, it pauses the upload. I have to switch back to Chrome so that it continues the upload. However, I have other things to do on my phone outside Chrome.

How can I configure Android so that when Chrome doesn't stop uploading when it doesn't have the focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I configure Android so that when Chrome doesn't stop uploading when it doesn't have the focus?

It seems that keeping the phone on charge seems to mitigate that issue. I've tested that behavior when uploading a large file to https://archive.org/upload/ and the behavior seems rather consistent: Chrome doesn't stop uploading when it doesn't have the focus if the phone is on charge, while Chrome does stop uploading when it doesn't have the focus if the phone is not on charge. I'm not sure if that behavior always happens, but it seems to often happens.

Note that this is a behavior specific to Chrome, as some other apps such as [utorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.utorrent.client&hl=en_US&gl=US) continue uploading when it doesn't have the focus even when the phone is not on charge.